# In Parse Need to fetch nested relation data in one call

Tags: react-native, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I am currently working with parse in react native.
I have a query that fetches data from a collection which has a property with relation to other collection. 
Now i want to fetch all these relational data in a single call rather then calling each relation separately.

Currently i get one collection then get its relational data separately in a new call.

```
const data1 = await result
      .get("data1")
      .query()
      .descending("createdAt")
      .find();
const data2 = data1.relation("test");
const data3 = await data2.query().find();
```

Now i want to fetch the relational data along with the data1 in the very first call.

I would like to know is it even possible in parse.
If yes how?
I have been trying to fetch relational data all day but no success.
Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're fine :)

Using relations, you will need to fetch the data with more than a single call.

**Why is it necessary?**

It is required because the relation type creates a new collection on the database to store the relational data.

Please, take a look at the code below:

```
query.find().then(results => {
    for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let object = results[i];        
        object.relation("data1").query().each(function(relatedObject) {
            console.log(relatedObject);
            /* .... */ 
        });
    }
}).catch(console.error());
```

**Is there another option to receive the data in a single call?**

Yes, there is! To configure this option, you will need to use the pointer or array type, then you will be able to use include() method and get the column value, please read more about it below:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#one-to-many